# Datas from database to custom List

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I would like to store some datas from a database to a list of a class.
Unfortunatly, my webpage is totally blank and totally emply...
This my code :

**CODE BEHIND :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Requête en chaînes de caractères qui sera utilisée pour récupérer les données dans la table Template
    string request = "SELECT Id, Name, Content From Template";

    // Process principal
    try
    {
        // Connexion à la base de données et à la table et utilisation de la requêtes SQL
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(request, connect);
        connect.Open();

        // Exécution de la requête SQL
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Si la commande comporte des lignes
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            sdr.Read();
            string temp_name = sdr["Name"].ToString();
            string temp_id = sdr["Id"].ToString();

            List<TemplateObject> Liste_template = new List<TemplateObject>()
            {
                new TemplateObject(temp_id,temp_name)     
            };
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = Liste_template;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    finally
    {
        connect.Close();
    }
}
```

**Code from the Class i created :**

```
public class TemplateObject
{
    string Id_template { get; set; }
    string Name_template { get; set; }

    public TemplateObject(string id, string name)
    {
        this.Id_template = id;
        this.Name_template = name;
    }
}
```

I would like to store and display an object which is composed of one TemplateObject and one FormObject, composed with two parameters (as TemplateObject) : id and name. I d'ont create the FormObject, because i'm starting with one at first.
I have to store my datas like this, beacause the datasource is a bit weird and i only work with strings.

Comment: "My webpage is totally blank" doesn't really tell much about the problem.  Are you getting an error?  When you debug, what specifically happens?

Comment: Maybe your SQL server is empty?

Comment: @BeGreen : My Database is full.

Comment: @David : I don't test with debug, but no error ... :'(

Comment: @ClémentPraudel: *"I don't test with debug"* - Then there's your first problem.  Actually debug it and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need a loop
- create the list before that loop
- fill the list in the loop

---

```
List<TemplateObject> Liste_template = new List<TemplateObject>()

while(sdr.Read())
{
    string temp_name = sdr["Name"].ToString();
    string temp_id = sdr["Id"].ToString();
    TemplateObject newObject = new TemplateObject(temp_id,temp_name);
    Liste_template.Add(TemplateObject)
}
```

Now you can assign it as `DataSource` of the `GridView`:

```
GridView1.DataSource = Liste_template;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: How can i forget the loop !!! xD What about the html code ? Have i add columns ? or Do i let the original

Comment: i use BoundField with the DataField property (value ="Id_template") and i have a error "Impossible to find a field or a property 'Id_template' in the selected data source". How is it possible ?

Comment: I manage finally to display the cColumns, because i forget to write "public" on my object properties.